# Fitbit keeps dying when reacing step goal when >~50% charge

Tags: fitbit

I have a Fitbit Alta and when it's around 50% charged (according to battery screen) or less and I get my step goal I find I can not turn it on. When I plug it in to charge, it shows the logo and the version number then shows it has less than a 10% charge. It only happens when I hit my step goal and not when I get phone notifications on it or when it does the hourly reminder to move. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: How old is the Alta? And can you explain your normal charge pattern, e.g. do you normally let the battery run most of the way down before charging it, or do you normally charge it everyday regardless of what level the battery is at?

Comment: @hardillb I don't know exactly how old the Alta is because I got it from my grandfather when he replaced it with an apple watch, but I think at most it is 4 years old. While I don't know how my grandfather charged it before this happened I would wait till about 25% before I charged it, and now I wait till it does the shutdown thing or when it is close to that percent,

Comment: In that case I would suggest that the battery worn out and it's probably not user replaceable.